Interesting Infinite Product Involving Subfactorials (Dearrangements)
I'm trying to compute:
\begin{gather*}
P =\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{i = 2}^n \left ( 1 - \frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{S_i} \right )
\end{gather*}
Where $S_i$ is given by:
\begin{gather*}
i!\sum_{j = 1}^{i-1} \frac{(-1)^{j - 1}}{j!}
\end{gather*}
I was quick to notice that the structure of $S_i$ closely resembled that of a subfactorial, and attempted to write it in that form:
\begin{gather*}
!n \equiv D_n = n! \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \\
S_i = i!+(-1)^i-i!\sum_{j = 0}^i \frac{(-1)^j}{j!} = i! + (-1)^i - !i
\end{gather*}
Substituting this all back into the product:
\begin{gather*}
P = \prod_{i = 2}^{\infty} \frac{i! - !i}{i! - !i + (-1)^i}
\end{gather*}
This is where I got to, and couldn't proceed, any help would be appreciated! Plugging it into Wolfram Alpha (substituting $!i$ for $\lfloor i!/e \rfloor$) shows that the product does indeed appear to converge, but does it have a close form solution that's computable?
Thank you for your help!

I saw this number $1.0503394893006753798$ but I cannot remember where.
